# preg_match a <link> href

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, href

I'm trying to do something I thought would be simple, but no luck.  The goal is to grab the href value from any  tag.  Example:

Source Material:

```
<link href="http://www.somesite.com/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

RegEx attempting:

```
<link[^>]*href=["{1}](.*?)["{1}][^>]*>
```

It seems valid at http://regexpal.com/, but I'm trying it at http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php, however, and it isn't working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have the `{1}` inside a character class `[]` when it should really follow after.  Actually, it isn't even necessary since it is implicit. But instead, you should use `[^"]` to match everything up to the next quote:

```
<link[^>]*href="([^"]*)"[^>]*>
```

**Note**: You're only attempting to match double-quoted href attributes. This will require modification if you expect to encounter any single-quoted attributes.

Obligatory public service announcement:  It is better to use a proper HTML parsing library to parse HTML and retrieve attributes than to try parsing it with regular expressions.

Comment: That did it - thanks!  I'm sure an HTML parser would be the way to go, but I only have 3 hours to go before the project is due.  Sometimes brute force is the answer.  :)